# Chrome glitching on launch in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, google-chrome

After the recent updates I have started noticing this weird gltich on chrome which causes my dektop apps to show up when I launch chrome. I thought it was just a one off bug but I have started facing this even more after the updates. Right now I am using chrome 94.0.4606.81 and the bug still persists.

This gif may explain what I'm trying to say:
[chrome glitching on launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byn8G.gif)

The output of chrome://gpu is:

```
Graphics Feature Status
  Canvas: Hardware accelerated
  Compositing: Hardware accelerated
  Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
  Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
  OpenGL: Enabled
  Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
  Skia Renderer: Enabled
  Video Decode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
  Vulkan: Disabled
  WebGL: Hardware accelerated
  WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
Driver Bug Workarounds
  adjust_src_dst_region_for_blitframebuffer
  clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
  count_all_in_varyings_packing
  decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
  enable_webgl_timer_query_extensions
  exit_on_context_lost
  msaa_is_slow
  disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
  disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
Problems Detected
  Accelerated video decode has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the 
  command line.
  Disabled Features: video_decode
  Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
  Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
  Mesa drivers in Linux handle varyings without static use incorrectly: 333885
  Applied Workarounds: count_all_in_varyings_packing
  On Intel GPUs MSAA performance is not acceptable for GPU rasterization: 527565
  Applied Workarounds: msaa_is_slow
  adjust src/dst region if blitting pixels outside framebuffer on Linux Intel: 664740
  Applied Workarounds: adjust_src_dst_region_for_blitframebuffer
  Disable KHR_blend_equation_advanced until cc shaders are updated: 661715
  Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced), 
  disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent)
  Decode and Encode before generateMipmap for srgb format textures on Linux Mesa ANGLE path: 
  634519
  Applied Workarounds: decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
  Expose WebGL's disjoint_timer_query extensions on platforms with site isolation: 808744, 
  870491
  Applied Workarounds: enable_webgl_timer_query_extensions
  Some drivers can't recover after OUT_OF_MEM and context lost: 893177
  Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost
```

I am using NVIDIA 1650Ti + integrated Intel graphics

Does anyone have any idea what is happening here ? Or is someone facing the same issue ? Also how can I fix this ?